# what is the best RX-JS operator for calling a service when the search term is more than 3 letters?

Tags: angular, rxjs

My requirement is that I need to call a **search `API`** when the query string is more than 3 letters so that I do not make more network calls. What is the best **rx/js** operator which can stop the service from being called, when the query is shorter than 3 letters?

Here's my code

```
    seaerchBooks= new Subject<string>();

  search(term: string): void {
      this.seaerchBooks.next(term);
          }

 this.books$ = this.seaerchBooks.pipe(
        // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
        debounceTime(300),
        // ignore new term if same as previous term
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        // switch to new search observable each time the term changes
        switchMap((term: string) => this.seaerchBooksService.search(this.authorId, this.genere, term)),
      );
```

Comment: Probably just `filter`, using the length.

Comment: hi @KirkLarkin can you help me with this where can I use the filter operator

Comment: Include in your question the code you have so far.

Comment: @Mahi Tej Gvp You only add distinctUntilChanged() if you need only. What if the name of a book contains last two (or more) characters same (for example JavaEE) ?

Comment: @siva636 In this pipeline, `distinctUtilChanged` ensures that the same *string* is not emitted twice in a row, not that the same *character* is not emitted twice in a row.

Comment: @Kirk Larkin I am sorry, I made a mistake here, you are right.

Comment: @siva636 No need to apologise. I just wanted to clear it up for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`filter`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) should be sufficient for what you need here. Here's the updated code:

```ts
this.books$ = this.seaerchBooks.pipe(
    // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
    debounceTime(300),
    // ignore new term if same as previous term
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    // ignore new term if fewer than 3 characters
    filter((term: string) => term.length >= 3),
    // switch to new search observable each time the term changes
    switchMap((term: string) => this.seaerchBooksService.search(this.authorId, this.genere, term)),
);
```

`filter` will simply filter out anything that does *not* match the condition provided - in this case, `term` values with fewer than 3 characters will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to use `debounceTime()` and `filter()` something like the following:

```
yourInputEventsAsObservable.pipe(
// wait until the user have a pause
debounceTime(500),
// only consider inputs that are more than 3 chars in length
filter(input => lengthOfInput > 3),    
switchMap((term: string) => 
this.seaerchBooksService.search(this.authorId, this.genere, term)),
)
```